How can I toggle the Word Wrap on the Left sidebar of Visual Studio Code?
Problem: The names can get long, being truncated. I wish I could see the title of the files or the headers in the outline even if my screen is small. Is there a way to toggle the word wrap for the left sidebar?


Have you considered moving that view to the bottom panel?

@wjandrea yes I thought about that, but that would take my vertical space.
I would rather use my horizontal space of my screen than my vertical space since my screen is rectangular.

This doesn't exist at the time of this writing.
You can turn on horizontal scrolling for list views using the workbench.list.horizontalScrolling setting. See also configure sidebar to be able to scroll horizontally visual studio code.
What you want was the subject of Wrap filenames in Explorer
#111411, which was closed as "out-of-scope" with a maintainer comment:

No plans to add this. But let's keep as a feature request for now.

I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
